# How to use Nextflow to call scripts from different environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pipeline, nextflow

I have the following conda environments:

- `wf-preprocess_env`
- `wf-assembly_env`

Each environment has unique dependencies installed.  I have 3 scripts:

- `preprocess.py` which I use with `wf-preprocess_env` environment
- `assembly.py` and `assembly-long.py` which I use with `wf-assembly_env`

**How can I use Nextflow to achieve a similar functionality to this?**

`wf-wrapper preprocess --flags` where `wf-wrapper` is a wrapper around Nextflow that allows me to have different modules that call different modules.

In the cases listed above,

- `wf-wrapper preprocess [--flags]` would call the `preprocess.py` script (and all the dependencies) that are in the bin of `wf-preprocess_env`.  I would also be able to provide it with different --flags such as -h for help or the arguments that are required to run (e.g., `-o/--output_directory`)
- Similarly, `wf assembly [--flags]` would call the `assembly.py` script and `wf assembly-long.py [--flags]` would call the `assembly-long.py` script both within the bin of `wf-assembly_env`.

My questions:

- How can I structure my main.nf Nextflow file to link a module with a specific script and specific environment to load the dependencies?
- Is it possible to wrap the main.nf file (e.g., wf-wrapper.nf) or is the only possibility to use the following notation: `nextflow run wf-wrapper.nf --module preprocess [--flags]`?

Note: At this point I'm not trying to write an entire pipeline in Nextflow, just to wrap existing scripts in Nextflow so I can easily access the conda environments in the backend.

My current code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

// Define available modules
modules = ['preprocess', 'assembly', 'assembly-long']

// Parse command line options
opts = parseOpts()

// Check if a valid module is provided
if (!opts.module || !(opts.module in modules)) {
    echo "Invalid module. Available modules: ${modules.join(', ')}"
    exit 1
}

// Define the process to execute the specified module
process wrapperScript {
    // Set the Conda environment based on the provided module
    conda "wf-${opts.module}_env"

    // Define the command to run the script with flags
    script:
    """
    # Assuming your scripts are in the bin directory of the Conda environment
    ${opts.module}.py ${opts.flags}
    """
}

// Execute the wrapperScript process
workflow {
    call wrapperScript {
        // Pass module and flags as input parameters
        input:
        module opts.module
        flags opts.flags
    }
}
```

But when I call Nextflow run it just gives me the Nextflow help:

```
nextflow run wf-wrapper.nf --module preprocess -h

Execute a pipeline project
Usage: run [options] Project name or repository url
  Options:
    -E
       Exports all current system environment
       Default: false
....
```

Comment: You get the nextflow help function because you invoke it by passing the `-h` parameter to the `nextflow run` command. Is this simply a flag you forgot to remove after running a previous command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `parseOpts()`, you might consider the [scope `params`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html) from Nextflow.

When you initialize parameters like this:

```
params.module = ''
params.flags = ''
```

It sets a default value for `params.module` and `params.flags`.
If you provide values for these parameters via the command line, these default values are overridden. Nextflow automatically assigns the values passed through the command line to the respective parameters in the `params` object.

For example:

- If you run `nextflow run wf-wrapper.nf --module preprocess --flags '-h'`, then `params.module` will have the value `'preprocess'`, and `params.flags` will have the value `'-h'`.
- If you do not provide `--module` or `--flags`, then `params.module` and `params.flags` will retain their default values, which are empty strings in this case.

So your code would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

// Define available modules
modules = ['preprocess', 'assembly', 'assembly-long']

// Parse command line options
params.module = ''
params.flags = ''

// Check if a valid module is provided
if (!params.module || !(params.module in modules)) {
    println "Invalid module. Available modules: ${modules.join(', ')}"
    System.exit(1)
}

// Define the process to execute the specified module
process wrapperScript {
    // Set the Conda environment based on the provided module
    conda "wf-${params.module}_env"

    // Define the command to run the script with flags
    script:
    """
    ${params.module}.py ${params.flags}
    """
}

// Execute the wrapperScript process
workflow {
    wrapperScript()
}
```

You should now be able to run your Nextflow script using:

```
nextflow run wf-wrapper.nf --module preprocess --flags="-h"
```

Replace `--module preprocess` and `--flags="-h"` with your desired module and flags.

---

> Is there a way to provide `--flags` as positional arguments?

Nextflow does not natively support unnamed positional arguments in the same way some other scripting languages do

A possible workaround would be to use [Groovy's scripting capabilities within Nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html):

The Groovy script block, at the beginning of your Nextflow script, would capture all arguments. Extract the positional arguments from this list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

// Capture all arguments
def argsList = args.toList()

// Define available modules
modules = ['preprocess', 'assembly', 'assembly-long']

// The first argument should be the module
params.module = argsList.size() > 0 ? argsList[0] : ''

// Remove the first element (module) and treat the rest as flags
params.flags = argsList.size() > 1 ? argsList[1..-1].join(' ') : ''

// Check if a valid module is provided
if (!params.module || !(params.module in modules)) {
    println "Invalid module. Available modules: ${modules.join(', ')}"
    System.exit(1)
}

// Rest of your script
```

`argsList` holds all the arguments passed to the script. The first argument (`argsList[0]`) is expected to be the module, which is assigned to `params.module`. The remaining arguments are considered flags and are concatenated into a single string assigned to `params.flags`.

You would then run your script with:

```bash
nextflow run wf-wrapper.nf preprocess -h -o /output/directory
```

`preprocess` would be here treated as the module, and `-h -o /output/directory` are treated as flags. The script concatenates these flags into a single string and passes them to the corresponding process.

Comment: Is there a way to provide --flags as positional arguments?

Comment: @O.rka I have edited the answer to address your comment/question.

Comment: Awesome thank you.  Only edit I would put in the original implementation is that you need to do —flag=“-h” in quotes (that’s the only way I could get it to work)

Comment: @O.rka Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.